# Backward pass on convolutional layer with 3-channel images

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, convolution

I know that deconvolution is basically convolution of output with flipped filters and I have implemented it for 2D data. But I am not able to generalize it for 3D data. For example consider the input of dimension `3x5x5` and the filter is of dimension `3x3x3` and stride is set to 1. SO, the output will be of the dimension `1x3x3`. What I don't understand is how to calculate the deconvolution for this output. The flipped filter again will be of dimension `3x3x3` and output of convolution is of dimension `1x3x3` which are incompatible for convolution. So how can we calculate deconvolution ?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this [post](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/12110) will help you out a bit. You are correct in saying that a filter of the same size cannot fit the deconvolution dimensions. So in order to remedy that, the 1x3x3 gets padded throughout with zeros, mean-values, nn, etc. until it is the appropriate size that you require. Depth can be handled the same way. In your example, you want a 3x3x3 filter to 'deconvolve' the 1x3x3 to a 3x5x5. So we pad out the 1x3x3 to a 5x7x7 (with whichever method you prefer), and apply the filter. There are definite drawbacks with this process, stemming from the fact that you're trying to extrapolate more information from less.